# How much is keifel for Gneivas Daas?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

When one steals knowledge (Gneivas Daas) and gets caught by witnesses, how does he pay back double?

PS.
Why is there no Gzeilas Daas?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: IIRC it depends on if its a cow or a sheep

Comment: The [ACDN](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14427/where-is-the-balm-in-gilead#comment26612_14427) needs backup!!

Comment: @HodofHod, [I don't think the ACDN is allowed by Halachah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14774/5).

Comment: @SethJ Now _that_ made me laugh out loud!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the very act of the theft he's already paid it back double.

How so? דעת equals 474, so a double payment for that would be 948. This is the gematria of the verse (Ps. 116:11):

> אני אמרתי בחפזי כל האדם כזב
>
> "I said in my haste, 'All people are deceitful.'"

- which is what the victim now knows to be true in one more case than he did before.

Answer (score 4):

As for why there is no 'Gzeilas Daas' the answer is simple! Someone stole and destroyed the concept from Jewish Law and Thought. There was a Gneivas Daas of Gzeilas Daas!!