# Need some good Russian Purim/kiruv links

Tags: product-recommendation, purim, translation, kiruv-outreach

I was totally shocked today, talking with one of my Russian colleagues.  He had absolutely no idea what Purim was about.  Not Mordechai, not Ester, not Achashverosh, not Haman - he didn't even know the Jewish people had been in exile in Persia.

But now he's interested.  So I've sent him a couple of links in Hebrew and English, but since I don't understand a word of Russian, I have no idea what good Russian kiruv resources are available.

Can you please recommend a few, especially ones that explain Purim for people who have **absolutely zero** knowledge to start with?

Comment: translate.google.com :P

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?as_q=purim&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_ru&cr=&as_qdr=all

Comment: What about Bucharaian?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Russian Chabad.org](http://www.ru.chabad.org/)

I can read, but not understand, Russian, but right there on the home page there's a picture of two masks with a link that says ["Пурим"](http://www.ru.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/549018) (which transliterates to "Purim").

Also, [JudaisminRussian.com](http://www.judaisminrussian.com/) (a division of [Friends of Refugees of Eastern Europe (FREE)](http://www.russianjewry.org/)).

---

For print materials, I know Kehos has good outreach materials [in Russian](http://store.kehotonline.com/index.php?parentid=101&deptid=3284), they're in use in Chabad Houses the world over, especially Russia.

I'd say most, but not all, of the Russian books there are at an introductory level, so that's something to think about.
But here's [the Complete Story of Purim](http://store.kehotonline.com/index.php?stocknumber=R-COMPPU&deptid=3284&parentid=101&page=1&itemsperpage=10) in Russian.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check with [Shvut Ami](http://shvutami.org.il/), an organization that exists to do and enable outreach in the Russian community. They operate outreach [centers](http://shvutami.org.il/programs/reaching/) in Israel as well as a [publishing house](http://shvutbks.com) that publishes and curates Russian translations of Jewish classics.

I found one explicitly Purim-related offering in the publishing house: [Megillat Esther - with transliteration](http://shvutbks.com/?book=12090):

> Colorfully illustrated edition with Hebrew text and Russian translation. The laws and customs of Purim are also included.

Comment: The [ACDN](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14427/where-is-the-balm-in-gilead#comment26784_14427) to the rescue! ;D

Comment: @HodofHod, ... and angling for http://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/58/sportsmanship , perhaps? ;^)

Comment: Actually, wasn't thinking about that, but now that you mention it....

Comment: In all seriousness though, a good post deserves an upvote, regardless of badges, competition, CD's, etc... The Ninja is just for the fun! Wheeeee!