# What bracha do you make when smelling non-edible flowers?

Tags: blessing, smell

I know about the bracha "borei atzei besamim". I understand this bracha to apply to edible spices and herbs and spices such as sage and rosemary. What bracha, if any, would I make if I smell other flowers. Does it matter if the flowers are cut and in a vase vs. still on the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch OC 216:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=253) states that if the smell is from a tree (or woody plant -- Mishnah Berurah) then the bracha is בורע עצי בשמים Borei Atzei Vesamim, if it is from a grass the bracha is בורא עשבי בשמים Borei Isvei Vesamim, and if it is not from either of those the bracha is בורא מיני בשמים Borei Minei Vesamim, except that if it is from an edible fruit the bracha is הנותן ריח טוב בפירות Hanotein Reiach Tov Bapeirot.

If you can't tell which category a certain thing belongs in, use בורא מיני בשמים (ibid.).

Comment: [There's also a fifth type of smell bracha...](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14427/where-can-i-get-afarsimon-oil/29763#comment74546_14427)